# How can I prevent <Title> appearing in <Table of Contents> in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

The first row of the table of contents is displaying text with the "Title" formatting, how can I prevent this from appearing?

Answer (score 3):

Select the 'Title' style (Format - Styles and Formatting), then, Modify, Paragraph and change the 'Outline level' to be Body Text

Update TOC